# Create a navigation menu using Twig

Tags: php, html, templates, twig

How do you create a navigation menu using Twig?  Note that I am not using Sympony2.

Given the following array passed to a Twig template:

```
$menu_main=array(
    'active'=>2,
    'menu'=>array(
        array('components_id'=>2,'name'=>'First Link','newwindow'=>0),
        array('components_id'=>3,'name'=>'Second Link','newwindow'=>0),
        array('components_id'=>7,'name'=>'Third Link','newwindow'=>1),
        array('components_id'=>8,'name'=>'Forth Link','newwindow'=>0)
    )
);
```

I am trying to create the following navigation menu:

```
<ul>
    <li class="first active"><a href="index.php?cid=2">First Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?cid=3">Second Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?cid=7" target="_blank">Third Link</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="index.php?cid=8">Forth Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Below is my non-working attempt:

```
{#
menu_main is an associated array containing active key and menu key.
menu is an associated array of containing name, components_id, and whether it should open a new window
#}
<ul>
    {% for item in menu_main.menu %}
    <li
    {% if item.components_id == menu_main.active %}
    class="active"
    {# How do I add first and last class?  Maybe using length? #}
    {% endif%}>
    <a href="{{ item[0] }}">{{item[1]}}{% if item.newwindow %} target="_blank" {% endif%}></a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you. 
As $main_menu['menu'] array is associative twig won't understand item[0] or item[1]

```
{#
menu_main is an associated array containing active key and menu key.
menu is an associated array of containing name, components_id, and whether it should open a new window
#}
<ul>
    {% for item in menu_main.menu %}
    {% set classes = "" %}
    <li
    {% if item.components_id == menu_main.active %}
        {% set classes = classes~' active ' %}
    {% endif%}>
    {% if loop.first %}
        {% set classes = classes~' first ' %}
    {% elseif loop.last %}
        {% set classes = classes~' last ' %}
    {% endif %}
    <a class="{{ classes }}" href="index.php?cid={{ item['components_id'] }}">{{item['name']}}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Gotcha about the associated arrays.  What about adding the "first" and "last" class names?  This will just add the "active" class.

Comment: You can use 'loop.first' and 'loop.last' inside for loop. I will edit answer for it.

Comment: Thank you! Just started using Twig.  I like it :)  But there is so much I don't yet know :(

Comment: Ah, I see you use `~` to append.  Thanks again!